# upgrading Pandas - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy'

Tags: python

I have Pandas version 0.24.1 on Python2 :

Python version:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ python -V
Python 2.7.13
```

Pandas version:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> pandas.__version__
u'0.24.1'
```

but need to upgrade Pandas for Python3.  I have tried to update Pandas using on the Linux terminal using:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

However the following error was returned:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ pip3 install --upgrade pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/de/a0d3defd8f338eaf53ef716e40ef6d6c277c35d50e09b586e170169cdf0d/pandas-0.24.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz>=2011k (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/28/1d3920e4d1d50b19bc5d24398a7cd85cc7b9a75a490570d5a30c57622d34/pytz-2018.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.12.0 (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/bf/4981bcbee43934f0adb8f764a1e70ab0ee5a448f6505bd04a87a2fda2a8b/numpy-1.16.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting six>=1.5 (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/73/fb/00a976f728d0d1fecfe898238ce23f502a721c0ac0ecfedb80e0d88c64e9/six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, pytz, numpy, pandas
  Found existing installation: six 1.11.0
    Uninstalling six-1.11.0:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/shutil.py", line 544, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link: '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/__pycache__/six.cpython-36.pyc' -> '/tmp/pip-mq4rdaea-uninstall/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/__pycache__/six.cpython-36.pyc'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 365, in run
    strip_file_prefix=options.strip_file_prefix,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/shutil.py", line 559, in move
    os.unlink(src)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/__pycache__/six.cpython-36.pyc'
```

I then tried : `python3 -m pip install pandas`

and received the same type of error:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ python3 -m pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/de/a0d3defd8f338eaf53ef716e40ef6d6c277c35d50e09b586e170169cdf0d/pandas-0.24.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2011k in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from pandas)
Collecting numpy>=1.12.0 (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/bf/4981bcbee43934f0adb8f764a1e70ab0ee5a448f6505bd04a87a2fda2a8b/numpy-1.16.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/17/c62faccbfbd163c7f57f3844689e3a78bae1f403648a6afb1d0866d87fbb/python_dateutil-2.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.5.0->pandas)
Installing collected packages: numpy, python-dateutil, pandas
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 365, in run
    strip_file_prefix=options.strip_file_prefix,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 854, in install
    strip_file_prefix=strip_file_prefix
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1069, in move_wheel_files
    strip_file_prefix=strip_file_prefix,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy'
```

How can I upgrade pandas?

Comment: It looks like you might have installed with ```sudo pip``` at some point in the past. Does that sound possible? In that case, ```sudo pip3 install pandas``` would fix this. However, ```sudo pip install``` is not recommended

Comment: Thanks Jack.  I ran sudo pip3 install pandas and it looks to have completed, but when I check my version of pandas its still 0.24.1.  Is there something else I can try, would it make sense to update python to 3.7 (would it update pandas as well)? If so could you let me know the commands to upgrade my python please? Thx

Comment: pandas 0.24.1 *is* the latest release of pandas. Upgrading to python 3.7 will have no impact on your pandas install